# ORC files with Hive: java.io.IOException: Two readers

Tags: hive, orc, hdp

I have an ACID hive table, with files in ORC format. When attempting a compaction, I end up with the following error: `Task: ... exited : java.io.IOException: Two readers for ...` The full error is as follow:

```
2019-06-03 07:01:05,357 ERROR [IPC Server handler 2 on 41085] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1558939181485_29861_m_000001_0 - exited : java.io.IOException: Two readers for {originalWriteId: 143, bucket: 536870912(1.0.0), row: 3386, currentWriteId 210}: new [key={originalWriteId: 143, bucket: 536870912(1.0.0), row: 3386, currentWriteId 210}, nextRecord={2, 143, 536870912, 3386, 210, null}, reader=Hive ORC Reader(hdfs://HdfsNameService/tbl/delete_delta_0000209_0000214/bucket_00001, 9223372036854775807)], old [key={originalWriteId: 143, bucket: 536870912(1.0.0), row: 3386, currentWriteId 210}, nextRecord={2, 143, 536870912, 3386, 210, null}, reader=Hive ORC Reader(hdfs://HdfsNameService/tbl/delete_delta_0000209_0000214/bucket_00000, 9223372036854775807)]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger.ensurePutReader(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:1171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger.<init>(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:1126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRawReader(OrcInputFormat.java:2402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.txn.compactor.CompactorMR$CompactorMap.map(CompactorMR.java:964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.txn.compactor.CompactorMR$CompactorMap.map(CompactorMR.java:941)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)
```

This table is created and updated by `merge`'ing avro files into an orc table, hence the bunch of deltas, both `delete_delta` and `delta`.

I have many other such tables, which do not have this issue. This table has nothing out of the ordinary and is actually quite small (<100k rows, 2.5M on disk) and was in the last month updated 100 times (20k rows updated, 5M update data). The DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_group`(
  `id` bigint,
  `license_name` string,
  `campaign_id` bigint,
  `name` string,
  `is_system` boolean,
  `is_test` boolean,
  `is_active` boolean,
  `remarks` string,
  `updated_on_utc` timestamp,
  `created_on_utc` timestamp,
  `deleted_on_utc` timestamp,
  `sys_schema_version` int,
  `sys_server_ipv4` bigint,
  `sys_server_name` string,
  `load_ts` timestamp)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://HdfsNameService/dwh/vault/contact_group'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'bucketing_version'='2',
  'last_modified_by'='hive',
  'last_modified_time'='1553512639',
  'transactional'='true',
  'transactional_properties'='default',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1559522011')
```

This happens every few months. As everything else (select, merge) works, the fix is usually to create a second table (`create table t as select * from contact_group`) and switch the tables, but I would like to find the real underlying reason.

The *only* reference I found about my error is in the [code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/orc/OrcRawRecordMerger.java#L1190) itself, which does not help me much.

This is on hdp3.1, with Hive 3.

Comment: Did you still have such issues? I'm having trouble with this one as well. Can you share the DDL and reproduction steps for your merge operations?

Comment: @user7644509 Unfortunately I left this job and this problem behind me. As far as I know, it has not been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I could not resolved the problem using the solution suggested by @ShuBham ShaRma.
After looking at @cang_yun's finding, I tried to delete one of the bucket file (bucket_00001) and was able to run select statements on that table again. I'm not sure that this is the right way to do it, but it worked in my case.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. The answer is detailed and clear but it could be a reply to the answer.

Comment: thanks @jacobkim, I understand. Unfortunately, it requires 50 reputation for me to be able to add a comment to other's answers, so I had to add an answer on my own.

Comment: I userstood and hope to see next time with your better answer on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the problem too.Through orc-tools I scan all files under delete_delta and it can be found that all the rows are same in these files(For example, there are 7 rows in bucket_00000, and the same 7 rows in the other file bucket_00001.).So the key(originalTransacion-bucket-rowId-currentWriteId)will be same when iterate the next bucket file.

Another fix is to create the table as bucket, maybe can avoid the problem.

Comment: Interesting, good find, thanks. My table is already bucketed as it is a transactional table. So now I wonder why those duplicate rows are written, but that's one step in the right direction.

Comment: @Guillaume How did you fix this issue in case if the table is already buckted.

Comment: @manish  Unfortunately I left this job and this problem behind me. As far as I know, it has not been fixed.

Comment: @Guillaume Thanks. For letting me know. Best Luck.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was caused from user error.  It is caused from two tables referring to the same hdfs directory.  When creating the table, I created the location name and accidentally copied the same directory to another table.

My program then performed changes on both transactional tables resulting in delta files that could not be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the summary for the observed issue for one of our users:

Table is failing during fetch task operation from disk, it got corrupted with duplicate key identifiers in delete_delta files (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22318), there is a temporary workaround to read the table by setting ***set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none***  but this would not help in compaction or any fetch task operations to succeed.

*Steps performed to create backup of table:*

- Connect with beeline and run below property in session:

  `set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none ;`
- Now you'll be able to run select statements over the mentioned table.
- Run below statement to create a backup for the table

  `create table <backup_tbl_name> as select * from <problem_tbl> ;`
- Once you have the backup ready, logout from session and check the
  backup table without setting any property, (check count and table
  consistency from data quality perspective)

  `select * from <backup_tbl_name> ;`

*To create original copy from backup table:*

- Now you can drop problem table and replace with backup table

  `drop table <problem_tbl> ;`

  `alter table <backup_tbl_name> rename to <original_tbl_name> ;`

***Note:*** To avoid this issue in future, create the table with a bucketing column in DDL

Comment: Is there any specific parameter based on which the bucketing column is seleted.

Comment: My table is facing this issue. I have tried these steps before but CTAS statement failed with same error of two files. I am trying to run major compaction, but that also fails.